# Size of MFT Vs Parsing of MFT

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, ntfs-mft

Am working in a project where i have to enumerate file names from a drive. I tried two methods

1. MFT parsing and
2. Multi threading with FindFirstFile. I compared the execution time of both implementation and it shows lesser the MFT size faster its execution and if MFT size is more than a GB it took more time to execute.

My observations are:

- Volume C: MFT Size : 1.85 GB     exe time : 65 sec     With core amount of threads : 9 sec
- Volume D: MFT Size : 38 MB       exe time : 0.593 sec  With core amount of threads : 1 sec
- Volume C:MFT Size : 1.02 GB     exe time : 11 sec     With core amount of threads : 3 sec
- Volume D:MFT Size : 89.75 MB    exe time : 1 sec      With Core amount of threads : 2 sec

P.s Measurements taken from two seperate machines.

With these observations, am a little bit confused that whether parsing of MFT depends upon the size of it? Why threading not provides better solution for MFT of smaller size?

Comment: No it depends on amount of MFT entries.

Comment: @user2120666 MFT holds current entries as well as deleted entries, So it should take more time even when size is low.With threads, only what are all in the drive currently are enumerated then why showing more time when MFT size is low ?

Comment: This question is very vague, because we dont know how is this measure performed (is same disk or not, is fragmented or not, how many entries is in the MFT(this is not same as size),etc.)

Comment: @Xearinox The Check is on same disk only. Size of MFT can be calculated by cmd -> run as admin-> defrag driveid /A /V . A list of details are available from where MFT size,fragment details and Record Count are calculated.

Comment: And how is performerd this measure on same disk? I dont understand.

Comment: @Xearinox..The System comprises of Single Physical Disk only..

Comment: So how is this measures, if you have only one disk?

Comment: @Xearinox The measure i gave above is for a Single Volume in a Disk.

Answer (score 2):

Multithreading with `FindFirstFile` is unlikely to provide you any benefit. If you have two separate threads going after the same physical disk, then you will incur unnecessary disk head seeks, which will mean more time to satisfy a read, which could quite possibly cause a multithreaded version using `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` to be *slower* than a single-threaded version.

Walking the MFT could potentially be faster than using FindFirst/FindNext, but at the expense of quite a lot of extra work. And, unless you have some special knowledge of the disk, probably wouldn't be faster *enough* to justify the expense of writing code to work at that lower level. And quite likely would be slower in the general case. I suspect that the NTFS developers and whoever wrote FindFirstFile / FindNextFile know a thing or two about the MFT that most of us don't, including how to walk it efficiently.

Comment: Now a days pc's and Laptops are coming with sufficient disk heads and the multithreaded version which i implemented seems to work for me as i got the list of file names from a volume in 3-8 sec itself. Now my question is about the MFT, and comparison of both of these two.I observed parsing the MFT takes more time when its size is large and is that true that larger the size slower the parsing ?

Comment: @WarriorPrince Multiple disk heads don't matter. A physical drive can only read/write one location at a time, and it gains a **lot** of performance benefit from low-level caching within the driver. By using multiple threads you may nullify the benefits of that caching and end up with slower performance. See this answer http://superuser.com/questions/365875/can-hard-disks-read-and-write-simultaneously-on-different-tracks-how